# Multiple property files for same Spring Boot Application based on request

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-config

I have a Spring Boot application for UI test automation using Cucumber and Selenium.
The application is expected to test multiple environments.
To begin with I have created json files with required properties like URLs, credentials etc. and load it(pass the file path as a property and use it) while triggering the test (`mvn test -DconfigFile=config/env1_config.json`).

I see that using profiles while running test is an option`-Dspring.profiles.active=client1` but as i will configure multiple pipelines in Jenkins for testing multiple environments to use same project with different configuration files, it will clone the entire project and run tests in workspace corresponding to the pipeline. To avoid keeping multiple copies of the project, i am planning to use Rest API to trigger Selenium tests and have configuration files in Git.

Is it possible to create multiple application properties files with custom properties, place them in Git and use required property file in a Spring Boot application(inside a Rest API impl) based on a property or RequestParam using Spring Cloud Config or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sharing the approach I ended up with as it might help someone someday.

As i wanted to create a Rest API and use properties from different config files in API implementation, based on the api request,
I created a Spring Cloud Config Server application that connects to application properties repo in git and  I consumed Rest APIs exposed by Spring Cloud Config Server (host:port/app/profile) in the service layer of my Rest API implementation.

Answer (score 0):

you can use spring boot profiles and pass it as maven argument

just pass `-Dspring.profiles.active=test1` as command line argument

you can read more [here](https://mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-profile-based-properties-and-yaml-example/)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by setting `spring.profiles.active` environment variable. Like if you are using property file for every environment by convention application-dev.properties, application-qa.properties. You can define you `spring.profiles.active` as dev and qa.

You can refer to the below link for more in site on same.

https://stackabuse.com/spring-boot-configuring-properties/

Answer (score 0):

You can use Spring cloud server and client.

Make A project With Dependency `Spring cloud server` and make config file(appilcation.properties) there. For use that config file in other microservice
just add spring cloud cilent dependency in other projects and add this line in application.properties

```
spring.cloud.config.uri:[your spring cloud server project url]
```

refrence:-

1. spring cloud server:-
   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gb1i4WyWNK4&list=PLqq-6Pq4lTTaoaVoQVfRJPqvNTCjcTvJB&index=11
2. spring cloud client:- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E2HkL766VHs&list=PLqq-6Pq4lTTaoaVoQVfRJPqvNTCjcTvJB&index=12